# Apply a style for 4 blogs and another style for the next 4 blogs in wordpress blog page?

Tags: posts, blog-page

I tried to customize my blog page. The first 4 blogs should be designed in one style while the next 4 blogs has a different style. When I applied the css, all the blogs were shown the same way. I was playing with have_posts() and the_post() functions.

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area dstC6 <?php echo $cols; ?>">
    <main id="main" class="site-main">

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <div class="blog-layout-grid clearfix">
        <?php
        /* Start the Loop */
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile; ?>

        </div>

        <?php

        the_posts_navigation();

    else :

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );

    endif; ?>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```

The template-part/content has the following code as below.

```
<div class="col-md-3 blogPostEach center-block">

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<figure class="entry-thumbnail">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'leto-large-thumb' ); ?>
    </a>
</figure>
<?php endif; ?>

<header class="entry-header">
    <?php if ( !$hide_meta ) : ?>
    <div class="entry-meta">
        <?php leto_show_cats(); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php the_title( '<h2 class="entry-title"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>
</header><!-- .entry-header -->

<?php if ( $show_excerpt ) : ?>
<div class="entry-content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?> 
</article>
</div>
```

Any suggestion on how to apply styles for every 4 blogposts in the code?

Answer (score 0):

In the following code you could add a class specifically based on the position in the loop:

```
<?php
    /* Start the Loop */
    $i = 1;
    $class = 'first-class';
    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

        if($i % 4 == 0){
            $class = 'second-class-'.+$i;
        }

        echo '<div class="'.$class.'">'

        get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        echo '</div>'
        $i++;

    endwhile;

?>
```

This is essentially a wrapper - it does not have to be a div, it could be a span - but it will count through the loop and change the wrapper class based on if the count in the loop is greater than 3 (first 4 posts 0-3). You then base your CSS off the wrapper class for greater specificity.

Comment: Thank you for the code. I need to apply it in a loop. one class for every post which repeats for every 4 posts in a row.

Comment: It's already in the while loop for the posts, but if you change `$i = 0` and the check for `$i > 4` to the above, where it is then checking if `$i` is divisible by 4 use the `class + $i;` not entirely checked, this is a bit on the fly.